# Three.js Manipulate an object from ObjLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js, objloader

I am trying to manipulate (e.g. change position, scale, rotation) an object loaded using OBJLoader in Three.js. While this is easy to do so once, I cannot work out how to do this when I want e.g. during the animate loop, or anywhere outside of the initial load callback.

Here is my code:

```
function loadObj( path, name )
{
    var obj;
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    mtlLoader.setPath( path );
    mtlLoader.load( name+".mtl", function( materials ) {
        materials.preload();

        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
        objLoader.setPath( path );
        objLoader.load( name+".obj", function( object ) {
            obj = object;
            obj.position.x = 20;
            scene.add( obj );
        });
    });
    return obj;
}

var myObj = loadObj( "assets/", "test" );

myObj.position.y = 20;
```

The key points to note here are:

- I can load it and manipulate it within the loop fine, and no errors are raised;
- If I do the above, I'll get an error on the last line, which states: `Cannot read property 'position' of undefined`.
- This error remains if I define `obj` outside the function (as a global), and then reference it accordingly.

I've tried similar code with the JSON loader, to the same results (I am able to manipulate it within the load, but not afterwards).

Comment: This is a question about `asynchronous` fetching of assets, like there have been countless before. Since the loader is asynchornous, the `object` will not exist before you its done, so executing things on it will fails. You need to move this to the callback or wrap it in a `Promise`.

Comment: @somethinghere pardon my inexperience, but how would you do so? Would you be able to link me to some relevant article? I'm rather new to javascript / three.js.

Comment: I have added an answer that shows how to wrap in a Promise. Just keep in mind that async requests (like loading something) never return something directly, and will always use a callback or a way to delay executing related code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loaders in `THREE.js` are asynchronous, so the best way around this is to simply use a `Promise`, or use the new await. Heres the promise implementation. I simply wrapped all the `THREE.js` loader code inside the promise and call `resolve` at the end. Then just use `.then` to execute whenever the asynchronous request is done.

```js
function loadObj( path, name ){
  
  var progress = console.log;

  return new Promise(function( resolve, reject ){
  
    var obj;
    var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
    
    mtlLoader.setPath( path );
    mtlLoader.load( name + ".mtl", function( materials ){
    
        materials.preload();
        
        var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
        
        objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
        objLoader.setPath( path );
        objLoader.load( name + ".obj", resolve, progress, reject );
        
    }, progress, reject );
   
  });
  
}

// This way you can use as many .then as you want

var myObjPromise = loadObj( "assets/", "test" );

myObjPromise.then(myObj => {
  
  scene.add( myObj );
  
  myObj.position.y = 20;
  
});
```

**Update** Corrected a little mistake where it would `reject` while `onProgress`. My Bad, read the THREE.js docs again and noticed that the order of `load` is `url, onSuccess, onProgress, onError`, so the final should be `url, resolve, () => {}, reject`.

Comment: Thank you for the very prompt answer. I've added this to my code and I get an error: `Uncaught (in promise)`, but I suspect that is because I am doing something stupid. Now that I know what the problem is, I can at least work towards fixing it properly.

Comment: @Jolyon Yeah the `uncaught` will have to do with an error while the promise was running, so it was rejected. I also added `reject` to handle any loaders that encounter errors. `Promise` is a really simple concept, have a read about it and it makes a lot of sense!

Comment: If I include a .catch after the .then, and log the error, I get continual `object ProgressEvent` errors. When I use `error.currentTarget` to see what it is, I get `object XMLHttpRequest`, yet `error.loaded/error.total` yields 1. I'm really not sure why this isn't working - it should be loaded yet the promise doesn't want to work. Any advice?

Comment: @Jolyon My bad, let me correct my answer... The thing is that where I used `reject` it is actually `onProgress`, so let me correct that... Sorry mate. Been a while since I read the docs on this.